# WoW addon for making binding spells/macros to mouse easy?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just bought a Razer Deathadder mouse. Since I use the Bartender add-on, I'm having a difficult time mapping spells/macros to my new mouse. I want to be able to add modifiers such as shift/alt/ctrl-clicking, etc. I have no way of telling what keyboard button my spells are with all of the stuff Bartender adds. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: As mentioned by @WerkkreW, the easiest way to do this is use Bartender's Keybinding mode. You just hover over a key and then hit the key or mouse button combination you'd like (so ctrl-MB5, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually use bartender for this purpose.  While I am unsure as to exactly what you mean by:

> I have no way of telling what keyboard button my spells are with all
>   of the stuff bartender adds.

I will try to describe how I do it with my mouse and my Nostromo.

First of all, Bartender can easily work with modifier keys, you simply enter key binding mode and press the combination (Alt-F) for example, and it will be bound.

I lay out my bars in whatever way I want them to look, put spells on the bars, and enter keybinding mode, hover over the button you want to bind, and press what you want - pretty simple.

Beyond that, you can do other things like hide the bars, or via the Razer configs map the mouse buttons to more standard keyboard buttons.

Comment: I Believe that he is in trouble trying to (ALT + left click) to use a macro or skill. Because the Key binder of Bartender is not recognizing that he pressed ALT together the left click, and only take the left click (or the ALT) to the Key bind.

Comment: Except that's not how the keybinding mode of Bartender works. You can't use chording keys (Alt/Shift/Ctrl) by themselves as a keybind, they only work as a chord of something else (including a mouse click).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about WoW, but if you have a program that operates your mouse, such as Microsoft Intellipoint (or iPoint), then you can use that to map the Keyboard commands themselves to the mouse instead. For example, you could change Mouse Button 4 to be Ctrl+5.

Answer (score 0):

By default Windows only recognizes 5 mouse buttons.  You have to [download and install the Razer driver](http://www.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=131&pcid=11) to fix that.

With the firmware, Windows recognizes the buttons, but WoW only looks for the first five. So the next step is to use the Razer driver to assign keys to the extra buttons.   Choose keys that are far away so you won't press them by accident, like `[];"'./=-`.

Once you have translated the buttons to keys, you can then assign them to an ability using Bartender.

And file a ticket so Blizzard and Razer can sit down together and improve this. :)